# Getting error when try to load texture from a file using SFML (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I am trying to load texture using SFML and return sprite but textures won’t load with my path. Full error says:
`libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Could not find texture with path: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-eqrudqhtua/Build/Products/Debug/Test.app/Contents/Resources/tile.png`

So I’ve declared in my `SpriteFactory.hpp`

```
class SpriteFactory

    {
        //function when I load sprite for the first time
        unsigned int LoadTexture(const std::string& texturePath);
       //function to create a sprite
        sf::Sprite GetSprite(unsigned int hash);
    
    private:
        //I’m using map to store textures
        std::map<unsigned int, sf::Texture> textures;
        
    };
```

Here the implementation in `SpriteFactory.cpp`

```
unsigned int SpriteFactory::LoadTexture(const std::string& texturePath)
{
    
    //load texture if it's not loaded and return sprite
    unsigned int hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(texturePath);
    //if the hash of our texturePath exist in the textures
    if (textures.find(hash) == textures.end())
    {

       // if it doesn't exist and reaches the end before texture
        if (!textures[hash].loadFromFile(texturePath));
        {
      
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not find texture with path: " + texturePath);
        }
  }
    return hash;
   
}

sf::Sprite SpriteFactory::GetSprite(unsigned int hash)
{
    if (textures.find(hash) == textures.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not find texture with hash: " + hash);

    }
    return sf::Sprite(textures[hash]);
}
```

When I put code part above in a comments just black screen appears.

In my `main.cpp` I load initial sprite textures

```
unsigned int tile = factory.LoadTexture(resourcePath() + "tile.png");
unsigned int tile_hl = factory.LoadTexture(resourcePath() + "tile.png");
```

Then I create a sprite sheet

```
Tile tilePart(factory.GetSprite(tile), factory.GetSprite(tile_hl),
              sf::Vector2f(100.f, 100.f));
    //draw it on screen
    tilePart.Draw(window);
    window.display();
```

My `Tile.cpp` part implementation is here

```
Tile::Tile(sf::Sprite tile, sf::Sprite tile_hl, sf::Vector2f pos)
{
    this->tile = tile;
    this->tile_hl = tile_hl;
    isHighlighted = (int)(pos.x /32) % 2 == 0;
    //set position of a sprite
    tile.setPosition(pos);
    
    //reference points to address, tile I'm gonna to render
    activeTile = isHighlighted ? &this->tile_hl : &this->tile;
}

Tile::Tile(const Tile& other)
{
    tile = other.tile;
    tile_hl = other.tile_hl;
    
    isHighlighted = other.isHighlighted;
    activeTile = isHighlighted ? &tile_hl : &tile;
}

void Tile::Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        if (isHighlighted)
        {
            activeTile = &this->tile_hl;
        }
    
        window.draw(*activeTile);
        activeTile = &this->tile;
    }

//whether we check highlights it will be set here
void Tile::SetHighlighted(bool flag)
{
   // isHighlighted = flag;
}
```

Could you please help to find out which part I've missed. Path is correct, I’ve tried many different ways: absolute path, I‘ve checked my image and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found an issue in my `LoadTexture` function implementation trough debugging. My image has loaded fine. The issue was with loading texture from file with `loadFromFile` (I didn’t load texture). If `loadFromFile` is true it should return `hash`. Only if it’s not loaded then it should return error. Here is my working code:

```
  unsigned int SpriteFactory::LoadTexture(const std::string& texturePath)
    {
        unsigned int hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(texturePath);
        if (textures.find(hash) == textures.end())
        {
            if (textures[hash].loadFromFile(texturePath));
            {
         
                return hash;
            }
        }

        if (!textures[hash].loadFromFile(texturePath)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not find texture with path: " + texturePath);
        }
    }
```